# DevExpress Button Click function does not work

Tags: javascript, button, devexpress

This should be really simple but it just doesn't work for me. I have this button:

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="btnStart" runat="server" Text="Start" 
    ClientInstanceName="btnStart">
    <ClientSideEvents Click="btnStart_Click" />
</dx:ASPxButton>
```

and this js:

```
 function btnStartToetsing_Click(s,e) 
    {
      ...logic...
    }
```

but using Firefox+Firebug and setting a breakpoint in the function, I see that clicking the button does not run the function. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the JavaScript function (btnStartToetsing_Click) is different from the assigned event handler name (btnStart_Click);

Use a name of the existing JavaScript function instead:

```
<dx:ASPxButton ID="btnStart" runat="server" Text="Start" ClientInstanceName="btnStart">
    <ClientSideEvents Click="btnStart_Click" />
</dx:ASPxButton>

function btnStart_Click(s, e) {
    alert('');
}
```

Comment: Your right, the names should of course match. But, When I posted, before the weekend, I tried to simplify names so I guess that the error was in posting, not in my original source code. Also, I already switched from clientside event to a regular, boring, OnClick event which gives me a ready-to-use callback provided by Visual Studio, that cannot fail. Thanks anyway for your help, I will keep this for my next try for a client side event in another form.